# Handling $resource request from PHP backend using SLIM

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm having problems accessing my PHP backend from AngularJS.

I have followed:

http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/02/sample-application-with-angular-js/

[Routing with AngularJS and Slim PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358333/routing-with-angularjs-and-slim-php)

Some other's too but those are similar. I've tackled the problem for a few days now and still can't get it working.

First way to call my php script

```
app.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl',function($scope, $modal, $resource) {
var request_Id = 1;
var Request = $resource('http://mobiiltelefonid24.ee/api/kasutatud_telefonid/'+request_Id);
$scope.request = Request.get();} //this way I get code 200 but 119 empty chars.. So I figure routing should be correct?
```

Second way I tried

```
app.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl',function($scope, $modal, Service) {
$scope.request =  Service.get({id:1});} //this gives me code 200 but 119 empty chars...

app.service('Service', function ($resource) {
return $resource('api/kasutatud_telefonid/:id', {}, {
    update: {method:'PUT'}
});});
```

PHP code (using mysql db)

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

$app = new Slim();

$app->get('/', 'getPopularPhones');
$app->get('/uued_telefonid','getNewPhones');
$app->get('/kasutatud_telefonid','getUsedPhones');
$app->get('/uued_telefonid/:id', 'getPhoneDesc');
$app->get('/kasutatud_telefonid/:id', 'getPhoneDesc');

$app->run();

/*Other get methods are exactly the same but with different name*/

function getPhoneDesc($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Phone";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $wines = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($wines);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

`getConnection()` is implemented as shown in wine app tutorial. There is one row in db that has 21 colums so it should return something. Also tried to pass string `$wine="teststring"` but that also arrived as jibbrjabbre.

Is routing wrong or is there problems with querying from db? (I can query just fine from phpMyAdmin). Out of ideas...

Comment: It looks like I'm not getting a connection to my db. It seems that host is not localhost anymore...
When I imported the wine application from github then wine db connected through localhost just fine but this one does not. Maybe I have to connect through some port?

Comment: Write something like echo 'Routed here'; as only line in getUsedPhones() and look in the console if this answer is returned. If not, the issue is probably related to a wrong slim setup. Enter the URL http://mobiiltelefonid24.ee/api/kasutatud_telefonid directly in the browser toolbar. Tell me the result and we will look further.

Comment: echo 'test' returned {"0":" ","1":" ","2":" ","3":" "} to console and the url leads to empty page.

Comment: Hmm, that's now what I expected. It should just return 'test' if this is the only line in the function. If I call http://mobiiltelefonid24.ee/api/kasutatud_telefonid/1 from here I get a 4 bytes result but can't see anything. But routing seems to work.

Comment: Maybe try a free php-mysql library like meekroDB http://www.meekro.com/ which has some advantages over pdo and some cool debugging features. Works very well with my slim setup.

Comment: Seems that meekroDB does not work as fine as it seemed or php script is corrupt. It cut's off some data at the end and puts empty spaces in the beginning can be seen here >> mobiiltelefonid24.ee/api/kasutatud_telefonid/1 PHP code as follows:  `function getPhoneDesc($id) { try { DB::$host = 'localhost'; DB::$user = 'correctinfo'; DB::$password = 'correctinfo'; DB::$dbName = 'correctinfo'; $result = DB::query("SELECT * FROM phones"); echo json_encode($result);     } catch(MeekroDBException $e) {       echo 'error';     } }`

Comment: Now it seems that `json_encode($result);` is messing things up because `var_dump($result);` gives everything I expect...

Comment: It's really strange when I leave `var_dump($result);` before my echo command it shows everything as expected in json also but when I remove `var_dump($result);` everything breaks down. What could it be, Slim cannot convert to json that fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Slim was falsely configured and meekroDB worked just fine (Thanks mainguy). On top of that there were some issues on webhosts side.

Comment: Solved the data problem also. Slims json_encode was corrupt somehow. As a solution I did'nt use Slim at all and wrote the routing logic myself.